# Easy way to show the foreign key value instead of the actual value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where one column refers to foreign keys of the ID Column of a second table. In another column I have stored names.

I would like to do a query where I get the full first Table, but with the values that refer to the second table replaced by the corresponding name.

**Table 1:**

```
+------------+-----+-----+
| Occupation | Age |  ID |
+------------+-----+-----+
|     IT     |  35 |  1  |
|  Teacher   |  22 |  2  |
|    ...     | ... | ... |
+------------+-----+-----+
```

**Table 2:**

```
+-----+-------+
|  ID | Names |
+-----+-------+
|  1  | Peter |
|  2  |  Jake |
| ... |  ...  |
+-----+-------+
```

**Expected result:**

```
+------------+-----+-------+
| Occupation | Age |  Name |
+------------+-----+-------+
|     IT     |  35 | Peter |
|  Teacher   |  22 |  Jake |
|    ...     | ... |  ...  |
+------------+-----+-------+
```

*I know that this is exactly what joins are for*, but is there a way to automatically replace all values by the foreign key value (in this example the name)? My tables are a bit more complex in reality with some of the foreign keys being nested (there's a third table that shows what value the foreign key actually refers to).

Comment: Create a function that accepts the id and returns the name. Create a calculated column in the table that calls this function and name it `Name`. Or don't, because it's awful and painfully slow. Use the join.

Comment: You'd just have to use `left` joins from the main table to the other tables, no way to automatically do this. If there is a nesting, you can use multiple left joins, eg: `m left join f1 on ... left join f1_1 on ...`

Comment: *"but is there a way to automatically replace all values by the foreign key value"*  No, you need to write the query, with the `JOIN`s and tell the RDBMS what columns you want; there is no "lazy option".

Comment: Hello @Sciurus-Alt-Del, based on the requirement for the query to return automatically the value of the column, I am afraid there is no such thing (based on what I know about SQL Server) since the join method exists, as there is no practical need for something different to exist. The joins pretty much get everything done based on your request. As you mentioned that the tables are rather complex and have nested FKs, you can prepare a view of the tables to have all the queries based on your need to be stored and reused.

Comment: The short answer is: No.

Comment: If you expect for a solution, show the problem.
This example is so easy and you are talking about nested tables. 
Nested tables, means nesting left or right joins depending on the result you are looking for.
Maybe your solution has evolved and your table design is obsolete.

Comment: A `JOIN` isn't always used to reference a "lookup" table either. If you had a `JOIN` that linked 2 tables, both with 25 columns, would you expect that if you didn't write that `JOIN` that SQL Server would replace that single foreign key column with 25 columns, from the other table? (You shouldn't). What would you expect to happen in a many-to-one relation ship. There's no such thing as an "array datatype" in SQL Server, so how would you display multiple rows in a single row? What you are after is not how SQL works.

Comment: @Larnu  Well, I suppose a `select *` with a [natural join](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/natural-join.php) could be nearest to a "lazy" join.  But it's probably a good thing that MS Sql Server doesn't support that join type (yet?).

Comment: I *really* hope they never introduce `NATURAL JOIN` to T-SQL, @LukStorms .

Answer (score 2):

This should help you - notice that I `SELECT` the id field twice - you won't want to do this normally, I left them both in so you can understand what's happening in the joins.

```
SELECT 
  t2.id t2.name,
  t1.id, t1.occupation, t1.age
FROM table_1 t1
JOIN table_2 t2 -- can use "INNER JOIN", the default. 
  ON t2.id = t2.id
```

p.s. although it's not required here, please always include the version of the RDBMS that you are using - it **can** be very important!

Comment: "*I know that this is exactly what joins are for, but is there a way to **automatically** replace all values*"?

Comment: Suspect because it doesn't give the OP a lazy option of "I can't be bothered to write my `JOIN`s. Why can't SQL Server be "clever" enough to just display the parent key" (apart, from that would break everything if that's how it actually worked).

Comment: Note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: BTW, `select * from t1 join t2 using (id)` will return only one id column.

Comment: @jarlh https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column_(database)#Field, also there is no `join using` in SQL Server.

Comment: "_The terms column, field, and attribute refer to structural components of tables, row types, and structured types,
respectively, in analogous fashion. As the structure of a table consists of one or more columns, so does the
structure of a row type consist of one or more fields and that of a structured type one or more attributes. Every
structural element, whether a column, a field, or an attribute, is primarily a name paired with a declared type._" ISO/IEC 9075-2:2016(E) aka ANSI/ISO SQL.